# create border radius iframe plugin

Tags: html, css

hello i run the css code to create a radius border, but only appears two of them, when the browser resizes i can see all the four radius borders, why this is happen?

this is my css and html code

```
iframe, #wbf{

    border-bottom-left-radius: 23px !important;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 23px !important;
    border-top-left-radius: 23px !important;
    border-top-right-radius: 23px !important;
}

 <div class="col-md-4" id="widget">

 <iframe id="wbf" src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/page.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FCl%25C3%25ADnica-Materno-Infantil-Casa-Del-Ni%25C3%25B1o-SA-399571326824453%2F&tabs=timeline&width=340&height=500&small_header=false&adapt_container_width=true&hide_cover=false&show_facepile=true&appId" width="100%" height="393" style="border:none;overflow:hidden;padding-top:0.5%" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>


 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The left two round corners appears after resized is because of you resized the browser to a certain size, as you set the width of `iframe` to `100%`, and it's parent container `div#widget` is a block element, so the iframe's width is always as same as it's parent DIV, and in your embedded page, the main content width is just about 340px, the left is blank (white background), so the top-right & bottom-right corder becomes invisible when `div#widget` width is over 363px ( main content width 340px + border radius 23px). So you should restrict the width of `iframe` or `div#widget`:

```css
#widget {
   width: 340px;
}
iframe, #wbf{
    border-radius: 23px;
}
```

```html
 <div class="col-md-4" id="widget">

 <iframe id="wbf" src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/page.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FCl%25C3%25ADnica-Materno-Infantil-Casa-Del-Ni%25C3%25B1o-SA-399571326824453%2F&tabs=timeline&width=340&height=500&small_header=false&adapt_container_width=true&hide_cover=false&show_facepile=true&appId" width="100%" height="393" style="border:none;overflow:hidden;padding-top:0.5%" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>


 </div>
```